# Replacing packages in new version of MikTex

Tags: packages, miktex, miktex2.9

Due to the update of MikTex some packages have disappeared.
It concerns the following packages:
Amssymb, textcomp, gensymb, color, enumerate, graphicx, inputenc

Does anyone know what packages replaces these? I know Amssymb is replaced with amsfonts, but I can't find the rest at all. I haven't used Tex in a while but these packages are in the template I use for every document I write with Tex. So I would like to have them back or something that is equivalent to their function.

Comment: `xcolor` is the long-extant sequel to `color`.

Comment: textcomp has not disappeared but is unneeded. None of the other package has disappeared either.

Comment: Most of those LaTeX packages are not gone, they are just contained in MikTeX packages of a different name. `amssymb.sty` (the LaTeX package) lives in [`amsfonts`](https://miktex.org/packages/amsfonts/files) (the MikTeX package). `textcomp` has been absorbed into the LaTeX kernel, so is no longer needed. [`gensymb.sty`](https://ctan.org/pkg/gensymb) lives in [`was`](https://miktex.org/packages/was/files). [`color.sty`](https://ctan.org/pkg/color) lives in [`graphics`](https://miktex.org/packages/graphics/files). ...

Comment: ... [`enumerate.sty`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) lives in [`latex-tools`](https://miktex.org/packages/latex-tools/files). [`graphicx.sty`](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) lives in [`graphics`](https://miktex.org/packages/graphics/files). [`inputenc.sty`](https://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc) lives in [`ltxbase`](https://miktex.org/packages/ltxbase/files). With MikTeX's on-the-fly auto-install feature you don't really have to worry about the MikTeX package names anyway, you can just have MikTeX install the required packages for you.

Comment: @moewe Thanks you so much, this was basically what I was looking for, maybe my question wasn't clear. I know most of them weren't simply removed but absorbed into other packages, I just didn't know in which ones they went. This makes it clear! If you make this into an answer I'll be glad to give you an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Most of those LaTeX packages are not gone, they are just contained in MikTeX packages of a different name.

It is not always guaranteed that a LaTeX package (`*.sty`) is shipped in a MikTeX or TeX live package of the same name.

| LaTeX package (`*.sty`) | Corresponding MikTeX package |
| --- | --- |
| `amssymb` | [`amsfonts`](https://miktex.org/packages/amsfonts/files) |
| `textcomp` | [`ltxbase`](https://miktex.org/packages/ltxbase/files) |
| [`gensymb`](https://ctan.org/pkg/gensymb) | [`was`](https://miktex.org/packages/was/files) |
| [`color`](https://ctan.org/pkg/color) | [`graphics`](https://miktex.org/packages/graphics/files) |
| [`enumerate`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) | [`latex-tools`](https://miktex.org/packages/latex-tools/files) |
| [`graphicx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) | [`graphics`](https://miktex.org/packages/graphics/files) |
| [`inputenc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc) | [`ltxbase`](https://miktex.org/packages/ltxbase/files) |

Many of these packages have a CTAN page, where you can find the respective names of the TeX live and MikTeX packages.

But with MikTeX's on-the-fly auto-install feature you don't really have to worry about the MikTeX package names anyway, you can just have MikTeX install the required packages for you.

TeX live users generally don't have to worry about TeX live package names because they just install the complete collection of packages or large collections.